# How do I pass internet traffic through localhost?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, localhost, server

I have created a local server using Python and I am trying to pass traffic to see the HTTP requests and responses.

I've tried the inputting the following into my browser and only get a 404:

> `http://127.0.0.1:8080/http://www.google.com`

For clarification sake I am trying to get the following:

```
>Starting simple_httpd on port: 8080<br>
>127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2015 15:12:33] code 404, message File not found<br>
>127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2015 15:12:33] "GET /http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: So essentially you're trying to make a proxy?

Comment: Yes it seems like I do. I looked a little more into proxies after you mentioned it and it seems way over my skill-set.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the browser to send HTTP requests through a proxy server you've developed running on localhost, you need to configure its proxy settings to point at (in your case) "127.0.0.1:8080."

On Chrome for example, you can do this in **Settings | Advanced Settings...** as per [this link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96815?hl=en). (Depending on OS, it will probably just bring you to the appropriate system-wide settings for your computer).

Another option is to edit your computer's hosts file to point the desired domain(s) at 127.0.0.1. If you go this way, you'll need to run your server on port 80.

Note that writing a completely-functional proxy server with good compatibility can be rather involved, but getting the basics up for experimentation aren't so bad. Also note that you'll generally be out of luck for SSL traffic.

BTW if you are just interested in seeing the request/response traffic, you might be better served with your browser's developer tools, or the excellent [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), which generally allow pretty good inspection of HTTP traffic in the "network" tab.